# big angle brackets

Tags: brackets, angle

I know that `\langle` and `\rangle` creates left and right angle brackets.  But they don't seem to adopt to the size of the expression inside.  For example, if I have a big matrix, I would like to angle brackets to be big as well.  How can I get this effect?

Comment: You can place \left and \right before each of them, respectively.

Comment: as for all delimiters in TeX use `\left\langle...\right\rangle` They have a maximum size though they do not get arbitrarily big.

Comment: `\left<` and `\right>` are abbreviations for `\left\langle` and `\right\rangle`, respectively.

Comment: @AriBrodsky  the point is that \left\right doesn't make delimiters big enough in this case, so \left< has same problem.

Answer (score 27):

The `mtpro2` package ([MathTime Professional II](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html)) provides extra-large (up to 10 cm tall) fence symbols -- round parentheses, square brackets, curly braces, angle brackets, etc. -- via its `\LEFTRIGHT` command. Note that the full `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge; however, its "lite" subset, which is all that's needed to produce extra-large fence symbols, is free of charge.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[
\LEFTRIGHT\langle\rangle{
\begin{array}{c} 
  1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10
\end{array}}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

**update** 2020-10-01: The pctex.com site noted in my answer no longer seems provide a functioning link to the page from which the `lite` subset of the `mtpro2` package used to be available for downloading. Many thanks to @mateuszb  for bringing this issue to my attention.

---

Comment: Usual comment about perennial enmity between the copy editor and the creator of such a horror. ;-)

Comment: Sadly the link on the company's page to the LITE version does not work anymore.

Comment: @mateuszb - Did their website maybe suffer an outage? I just checked https://pctex.com/mtpro2.html#Pricing. It still seems to be possible to click on the "FREE" link next to "MTPro2 Lite".

Comment: @Mico, the "Free" link is dead I believe. Thanks

Comment: @mateuszb - That's rather unfortunate. I'll edit my answer to put in a note that the website's link to the "lite" version of the font package appears to be dead.

Answer (score 23):

In the standard fonts `\langle` has a fixed upper limit and doesn't grow above a certain size. (TeX extends characters by adding vertical extension glyphs and angle brackets don't have a vertical section that can be extended). However if you don't mind distorting the shape you can scale the bracket to fit:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\[
\left\langle\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\end{array}\right\rangle
\]

\[
\sbox0{$\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\end{array}$}
\mathopen{\resizebox{1.2\width}{\ht0}{$\Bigg\langle$}}
\usebox{0}
\mathclose{\resizebox{1.2\width}{\ht0}{$\Bigg\rangle$}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The stretched angle brackets currently don't seem to be quite tall enough to "cover" the lower part of the bottom row. Is there an adjustment to achieve this coverage?

Comment: @Mico you can change `\ht0` to `1.1\ht0` or whatever factor you like You can also fiddle with `\raisebox{...}{\usebox{0}}` to adjust the position of the box within the delimiters (the more you scale the more the difference between centering on the baseline and centering on the math axis is apparent)

Answer (score 12):

This is the sort of thing the `scalerel` package was designed for.  WIth the use of the width-limited `\scaleleftright` or aspect-limited `\stretchleftright`, a desirable outcome can often be achieved.  In the below example, I show both, first employing `\scaleleftright` with a width limit of 1.75ex, and then showing `\stretchleftright` with an aspect limit of 1000% (i.e. stretch of 10).  Note that in all cases, the symbols being manipulated are the humble `<` and `>` symbols, not some predefined stretchable version.

Finally, in the third figure set, I show that one can use a stretched version of `\langle` and `\rangle`, instead of `<` and `>`.  Depending on the tastes of the user, one may be preferable to the other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}

\setlength\arraycolsep{0ex}
\(
\scaleleftright{<}
{x}
{>}
%
\scaleleftright[1.75ex]{<}
{\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z \end{array}}
{>}
%
\scaleleftright[1.75ex]{<}
{\begin{array}{c}u\\v\\w\\x\\y\\z \end{array}}
{>}
%
\scaleleftright[1.75ex]{<}
{\begin{array}{c}r\\s\\t\\u\\v\\w\\x\\y\\z \end{array}}
{>}
\)

\(
\stretchleftright{<}
{x}
{>}
%
\stretchleftright[1000]{<}
{\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z \end{array}}
{>}
%
\stretchleftright[1000]{<}
{\begin{array}{c}u\\v\\w\\x\\y\\z \end{array}}
{>}
%
\stretchleftright[1000]{<}
{\begin{array}{c}r\\s\\t\\u\\v\\w\\x\\y\\z \end{array}}
{>}
\)

\(
\stretchleftright{\langle}
{x}
{\rangle}
%
\stretchleftright[1000]{\langle}
{\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z \end{array}}
{\rangle}
%
\stretchleftright[1000]{\langle}
{\begin{array}{c}u\\v\\w\\x\\y\\z \end{array}}
{\rangle}
%
\stretchleftright[1000]{\langle}
{\begin{array}{c}r\\s\\t\\u\\v\\w\\x\\y\\z \end{array}}
{\rangle}
\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it out of all answers, but the example is quite long which is why I left it as the last thing to try!

Answer (score 0):

The nicest solution I can think of is using the [braket](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/braket) package.

```
\documentclass[class=article,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}
$
\Braket{
    \begin{array}{lcl}
               z & =  a \\
                 & =  a \\
        f(x,y,z) & =  x + y + z
    \end{array}
}
$

$
\Braket{
    \begin{array}{lcl}
               z & =  \frac{a}{b} \\[2ex]
                 & =  \frac{a}{b} \\[2ex]
        f(x,y,z) & =  x + y + z
    \end{array}
}
$
\end{document}
```

to get right angle brackets which adjust to size. Unfortunately, like other solutions here the brackets do not stretch when the vertical line spacing is increased.

[image]