# Extend vertically \langle and \rangle - paranthesis an environment {NiceMatrix} with Tikz-PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, stix

I'd like to extend vertically the `\langle` and `\rangle` -paranthesis in this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\[\begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width=8.5mm]
\diagbox{\small A_i} {\small A^j} 
\Block[hvlines]{1-4}{}
\Block[hvlines]{4-1}{}
& A^1 & A^2 & A^3 \\
A_1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
A_2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
A_3 & 7 & 8 & 9 
\CodeAfter
\SubMatrix\langle{2-2}{4-4}\rangle[xshift=-0.85mm]
\begin{tikzpicture} [dashed,shorten > = 2mm, shorten < = 2mm]
  \draw (3-|2) -- (3-|5) ;
  \draw (4-|2) -- (4-|5) ;
  \draw (2-|3) -- (5-|3) ;
  \draw (2-|4) -- (5-|4) ;
%[line,shorten > = 2mm, shorten < = 2mm]
  \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2-|5) -- (5-|5) ;
\draw (5-|2) -- (5-|5) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: You mean "extend vertically"?

Comment: Yes, I have just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution by drawing the angular brackets with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width=8.5mm,cell-space-limits=2pt,hvlines]
\diagbox{\scriptstyle A_i} {\scriptstyle A^j} 
& A^1 & A^2 & A^3 \\
A_1 & \Block{3-3}{}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
A_2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
A_3 & 7 & 8 & 9 
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{scope} [dashed]
      \draw ([xshift=3mm]3-|2) -- ([xshift=-3mm]3-|5) ;
      \draw ([xshift=3mm]4-|2) -- ([xshift=-3mm]4-|5) ;
      \draw (2-|3) -- (5-|3) ;
      \draw (2-|4) -- (5-|4) ;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope} [line width=1pt] 
      \draw ([xshift=-1mm]2-|2.5) -- ([xshift=1mm]3.5-|2) -- ([xshift=-1mm]5-|2.5) ;
      \draw ([xshift=1mm]2-|4.5) -- ([xshift=-1mm]3.5-|5) -- ([xshift=1mm]5-|4.5) ;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comments

- The command `\Block{3-3}{}` creates a empty block. With that block, the key `hvlines` will draw all the rules excepted in the blocks (in *that* block, in fact, here).
- The command `\diagbox` is a built-in command of `nicematrix`. So, there is no need to load the package `diagbox`.
- I have adjusted the positions of the points of the angular brackets by using `[xshift=...]` in the Tikz coordinates (this is a Tikz feature).
- The environment `{scope}` is provided by Tikz. It's a way to limit the scope of the options in a Tikz picture.
- As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

The command `\SubMatrix` available in the `\CodeAfter` of the environments of `nicematrix` has a key `extra-height` to increase the vertical size of the delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\[\begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width=8.5mm,hvlines]
\diagbox{\scriptstyle A_i} {\scriptstyle A^j} 
& A^1 & A^2 & A^3 \\
A_1 & \Block{3-3}{}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
A_2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
A_3 & 7 & 8 & 9 
\CodeAfter
\SubMatrix[{2-2}{4-4}][xshift=-0.85mm,extra-height=1mm]
\begin{tikzpicture} [dashed,shorten > = 2mm, shorten < = 2mm]
    \draw (3-|2) -- (3-|5) ;
    \draw (4-|2) -- (4-|5) ;
    \draw (2-|3) -- (5-|3) ;
    \draw (2-|4) -- (5-|4) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

**However, the delimiters `\langle` and `\rangle` have a maximal size** (see [that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108767/big-angle-brackets)). In you example, the default size is yet the maximal size and that why `extra-height` won't have any effect.

You could try to change the mathematical font as explained in the question linked above...

Comment: I've just seen this site [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108767/big-angle-brackets) but I have trouble with applicate it

Comment: Or if I draw those parenthesis with tikz, could it be good?

Comment: Furthermore, The `xshift=-0.85mm, yshift=-0.85mm` -commands are not very clear to me. Could You explain, please?

Comment: Does exist a way to write `\SubMatrix` without parenthesis? Thx