# How to make subscript follow the large angle instead of aligning with the bottom line of the equation?

Tags: subscripts, angle

I have the following latex code and I don't know how to align the subscript `f` with the `\rangle`.

Making the `langle` and `rangle` bigger is also possible but I didn't find a solution. I've tried to use `sbox0` but I failed.

My original code is :

```latex
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\left\langle\frac{a}
{
\begin{aligned}
b\\
c\\
d\\
e\\
\end{aligned}
}
\dots\right \rangle_{f}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

The result of XeLaTeX compilation is as follows:

[image: orign result]

How can I make the `f` following the `\rangle`?

Following instructions in [big angle brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108767/big-angle-brackets) and using `sbox0`, I changed my code as follows:

```latex
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sbox0{
\frac{a}
{
\begin{aligned}
b\\
c\\
d\\
e\\
\end{aligned}
}
\dots}
\mathopen{\resizebox{1.2\width}{\ht0}{$\Bigg\langle$}}
\usebox{0}
\mathclose{\resizebox{1.2\width}{\ht0}{$\Bigg\rangle$}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

And obviously I failed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Observe that I've gotten rid of both `aligned` environments. The outer one doesn't appear to be doing anything useful at all, and the inner one is best replaced with a `matrix` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
\[
\left\langle
\frac{a}{ \begin{matrix} b\\ c\\ d\\ e\\ \end{matrix}} 
\cdots
\right\rangle 
{\vphantom{\frac{a}{b}}}_{\!\!f} % '\!\!' is used to "snug up" the subscript term
\]
\end{document}
```